# Which Python web framework can I choose for a simple ERP system?

Tags: python, mysql, web-frameworks, erp

I want to create a simple ERP system which include Inventory system, Employee Payroll, Email system for users, reports and small service desk application. I want to make it a browser-based application.

Which Python web framework will support my requirements, and easy to develop and work with MySQL. It may need to to expand it in future.

Answer (score 1):

[**Django**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/) will best suit your requirment

Comment: Why is it best for those requirements?